# Hide closest div on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to figure out how to hide my divs on click, I have two foreaches so it will be multiple equal divs created meaning same class names and stuff so I figured using `.closest` to hide/show the one I click. If the foreach creates 4 divs and I click one of them I want that one to hide/show.

Also, see comments in following code

```
@foreach ())
{
    <div class="vwHoldLiftInfo"> // Bigger div
    <a class="liftVariTitle">@variants</a><br /> // Click THIS..

        <div class="vwSetRepHolder @cssClass"> // To hide THIS..

            @foreach ())
            {
                <a>@d.sett x @d.rep @d.kg</a><br />
            }

        </div>
    </div>
}
```

This is the script I tried with but it hides all the divs! Can this be done?

```
$(function() {
    $(".liftVariTitle").click(function() {
        $(".vwHoldLiftInfo").children('div').hide(); // .closest/.children?            
    });
});
```

Comment: `Im trying to figure out how to hide my divs on click` This is not very clear at all - you want to hide the div that's clicked? So why does `closest` or `children` matter?

Comment: At the moment the script I use will hide all divs on click but I only want to hide the div thats closest to the `a` tag that I click!

Comment: `This is the script I tried with but it hides all the divs!` what does this mean exactly?

Comment: that It hide all the divs when I only wanted it to hide one div, so it doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*I only want to hide the div thats closest to the a tag*) you need to use `$(this)`

```
    $(function() {
       $(".liftVariTitle").click(function() {
          $(this).closest(".vwHoldLiftInfo").find('.vwRepSetHolder').hide(); // .closest/.children?            
      });
   });
```

Comment: Okey, we are getting there, though I only want the `vwRepSetHolder` div to hide on click, so that the text you click on and the div above it is still there, make sense? Now the entire div did go away, but at least only the one I clicked

Comment: @PontusSvedberg You're welcome , Have a great day :-)

Comment: The same to you! :-)